# Arrange landscape and portrait image in a subfigure using latex

Tags: subfloats, landscape, subfig

I try to show a horizontally and a vertically picture in two subfigures beneath each other. How can I display both beneath each other without distorting one of them completely. I am completely fine if one or both change in size, as long as they are not skewed.

Here is my code and the result:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering     %%% not \center
\subfigure[minor Eiffeltower]{\label{fig:b}\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{content/images/Eiffeltower1.jpg}}
\subfigure[major Eiffeltower]{\label{fig:a}\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{content/images/Eiffeltower2.jpg}}
\caption{Picture is stolen from: $https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Tour_Eiffel_Wikimedia_Commons.jpg$}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to stack two figures on top of each other, rather than side to side. I don't have that much space sadly. I need a way to portrayal them side by side, in my real project the difference is not as big as in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a macro, which calculates the width of two pictures, so they have the same height in the document. After calling it, `\PicWidthA` contains the width for the first picture and `\PicWidthB` the width for the second one.

I used the `subcaption` package here, because the `subfigure` package you used is depreciated.

The code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newdimen\@picAx
\newdimen\@picAy
\newdimen\@picBx
\newdimen\@picBy
\newdimen\PicWidthA
\newdimen\PicWidthB
\newsavebox\imagebox
% #1: width of both pictures
% #2: gap between picture
% #3:
% #4:
\newcommand{\CalcPicWidths}[4]{%
    % get heights and widths of pictures
    \sbox{\imagebox}{\includegraphics{#3}}%
    \@picAx\wd\imagebox
    \@picAy\ht\imagebox
    \sbox{\imagebox}{\includegraphics{#4}}%
    \@picBx\wd\imagebox
    \@picBy\ht\imagebox
    % clear box
    \sbox{\imagebox}{}%
    % get final wdth of both picture (= #1 - #2)
    \@tempdima#1\relax
    \advance\@tempdima-#2\relax
    % width of pictures, second scaled for same height as first
    \PicWidthA\@picAx
    \setlength{\PicWidthB}{\@picBx * \ratio{\@picAy}{\@picBy}}%
    % width of both pictures
    \@tempdimb\PicWidthA
    \advance\@tempdimb\PicWidthB
    % final widths
    \setlength{\PicWidthA}{\PicWidthA * \ratio{\@tempdima}{\@tempdimb}}%
    \setlength{\PicWidthB}{\PicWidthB * \ratio{\@tempdima}{\@tempdimb}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \CalcPicWidths{\textwidth}{5pt}{example-image-16x9.png}{example-image-9x16.png}%
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{\PicWidthA}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-16x9.png}
    \caption{Subfigure A}\label{fig:1a}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{\PicWidthB}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-9x16.png}
    \caption{Subfigure B}\label{fig:1b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]